# dns caching in request module - node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, dns, node-modules

In my project I do a big amount of request to the same url using the 'request' module. For some reason a lot of the request go to the dns server in order to resolve the url address instead of having some sort of caching for this. Is there some kind of built-in mechanism in the 'request' module to resolve this? Or any other solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Same issue here, I've been told I'll be blocked for DNS attack when my server has grown

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This question is a little old so you may have already found an answer, but I just had this problem and used the [dnscache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dnscache) module to handle it. We had a high amount of IO (Node reading `/etc/resolv.conf`), and this module seemed to handle the problem. I couldn't find anything in Request's or Node's source to handle that problem, but did find [this related issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8436).

Comment: We had problems with our app overloading the DNS service in kubernetes, this post helped solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/lookup-dns-cache

Have encountered the same problem, so have created a package to solve it.

Comment: I find this to be the best answer. the module is simple and solves the issue like magic